# How to go to parent directory in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

I have created a Laravel 5.5 project and have placed few files inside the **app.Http.controller.Auth.myfolder.myfile**.

myfile has extension **myfile.blade.php**

I am trying to route the file as shown below

web.php

```
Route::get('/Sign-Up', function () {
    return view('app.Http.Controllers.Auth.publisher.register');
});
```

web.php is place in route folder and folder route and app are in same directory.

but this method is not working.

Comment: return view always search in resource/view folder if you want to search view in another location you have to configure which is not good way

Comment: Don't put views outside the default view location (as noted by @bipin) unless your really really have to (can't think of any reason why you would have to to be honest). If you must then you can register a new view namespace check out https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-implement-view-namespaces-in-l5